# Recommended way to reset in memory H2 database for each QuarkusTest

Tags: testing, quarkus

I'm implementing some BDD `@QuarkusTest`s using RestAssured and an in-memory H2 database. I'm looking for the *simplest and recommended* way to reset the in memory database (either drop-recreate or delete all entities everywhere) after *each* test.

I'd like to avoid any hands on ways like create custom `DELETE` scripts that run manually after each test of table truncates. Is there a clean and quarkus-native way to do this?

EDIT: Please do not recommend anything related to Flyway or other 3rd party dependency.

EDIT 2: I did a quick initial hack by dropping all entities manually but I'm looking for something simpler and automatic

```
  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
    try (final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()) {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.createNativeQuery("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE").executeUpdate();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      for (EntityType<?> entity : em.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final Class<?> managedType = entity.getBindableJavaType();
        em.createQuery("FROM " + managedType.getSimpleName(), managedType).getResultList().forEach(em::remove);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
      }
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.createNativeQuery("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE").executeUpdate();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: How about using `@TestTransaction` as mentioned in https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#tests-and-transactions ?

Comment: The test itself calls methods annotated with `@Transaction` (as expected) and this doesn't seem to work even though `TxType.REQUIRED` supposedly uses the existing transaction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a different and better answer is provided we'll go with the hack:

```
  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
    try (final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager()) {
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.createNativeQuery("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE").executeUpdate();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
      for (EntityType<?> entity : em.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final Class<?> managedType = entity.getBindableJavaType();
        em.createQuery("FROM " + managedType.getSimpleName(), managedType).getResultList().forEach(em::remove);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
      }
      em.getTransaction().begin();
      em.createNativeQuery("SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE").executeUpdate();
      em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use [DBRider](https://database-rider.github.io/database-rider/latest/documentation.html?theme=foundation). It fills the database with some data from a file and clears the tables before. Your test looks something like

```
@QuarkusTest
@DBRider
@DataSet(value = "datasets/your-test-data.yml")
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {}
}
```

The file with the data looks as follows:

```
table1:
    - id: 1
      col1: 'first value'
      col2: 'second value'
    - id: 2
      col1: 'third value'
      col2: 'fourth value'
```

In this example, the table 'table1' gets cleared before the test, then two rows will be inserted.

Comment: Interesting library but too much overhead for what I want to do at the moment :)